# How to append windows elements in WPF from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working with WPF and the MVVM pattern and I need to append elements to the window from the ViewModel. The scenario is: the user will have a collection of textbox simmulating fields of a table to insert products, and there'll be a button to add more rows. My problem is just to create a way to make this button works. How can I do that ?

Is there a better way to solve a problem like this ? Needing to add many entities at once adding rows to a table ?

Thanks in advance for your aid.

Comment: I would look into using the WPF DataGrid rather than create new textboxes for each record simulating a data table.

Comment: @Josh, is it easy to bind the rows of the DataGrid to the collection that I want to create ? Sorry if this question seems silly, I'm new to WPF and MVVM. Could you recommend somewhere I can learn more about that ? Thanks again

Comment: No worries.  Here's a link with a simple example:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ObservableCollection in your view model bound to an ItemsControl. On the button click event add a new object to the collection. The UI will be notified that another object has been added to the collection and render the new row.